# SQL query count from instances

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table contains bus and student sign up information:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BusSignupInstance](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BusId] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here are some sample data:

```
Id  StudentId   BusId
1   1   1
2   2   1
3   3   1
4   1   2
5   4   2
6   1   3
7   5   3
```

I want the total number by bus ID. In this case will be:

```
BusId    Num of Students
1      2 (student id 2, 3)
2      1 (student id 4)
3      2 (student id 1, 5)
```

The result is based on the order of sign up, if student 1 sign up three times, only the last time is effective.

Comment: How many distinct students and how many signups per student (in average) are you expecting in the table?

Comment: Hundreds of students and signups on the order of ~10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT  busId, COUNT(*)
FROM    (
        SELECT  busId, studentId,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY studentId ORDER BY id DESC) rn
        FROM    busSignupInstance
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
GROUP BY
        busId
```

Comment: @CrappyCodingGuy: you're right, didn't notice that they can sign up to different buses.

Comment: +1. Wondering beside using this query, if I added additional column to maintain a linked list(sign up sequence), will that be an overkill or a good schema change to make the query simpler? We do need support insert and delete of this table (no need for update).

Comment: @Icerman: why having a linked list if you don't want to update? Linked list is all about simplifying the updates.

Comment: @Quassnoi, make the query simpler and faster (without the sub query) won't be good enough reason?

Comment: @Icerman: linked list will not make your query simpler and faster. It would require a recursive `CTE` and is not good for anything but relinking it fast (traversing it is slow).

Comment: Oh, I mean we can query by using "where UpdatedBy is null" then we can get the last sign up entry.

Comment: @Icerman: it's a good solution if you track everything correctly on inserts and deletes, though I don't see how is it a linked list :)

Comment: In the above example, student 1 will have three entries: first one will be updated by the second(id 4) (Updated by using the identity column), and so on. So effectively a linked list. But as you mention, we will pay the price on insert and delete.

Comment: @Icerman: if you just use it to find the last entry, then it's a nice solution.